# ReferenceError: Console is not defined

Tags: meteor

I am working on a bingo game with Meteor.  I am now getting an error and since it is in the JS file (and I am writing Coffee), I have no idea where it's coming from.

Here is the full error:

```
ReferenceError: Console is not defined
    at app/Bingo.coffee.js:465:12
    at run (/Users/ppedrazzi/Dropbox/Paul's Stuff/MyApps/Meteor/bingo/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:283:63)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at run (/Users/ppedrazzi/Dropbox/Paul's Stuff/MyApps/Meteor/bingo/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:283:7)
```

I have placed the coffee and html file in a gist here: 
https://gist.github.com/ppedrazzi/5303493

Thank you for any insight!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like line 334 of your `bingo.coffee`.

In javascript everything is case sensitive so using a lowercase `c`

```
console.log "Server started and collections cleared."
```

instead of

```
Console.log "Server started and collections cleared."
```

is likely to fix the syntax error

Comment: Thanks Akshat!  I knew it was something dumb.  Incidentally, how can you trace back to the Coffee file line in a case where the error only references the JS file?

Comment: I'm not too sure its that easy with meteor itself, I think you would have to use the coffeescript cake tools for debugging in greater detail

Answer (score 6):

Instead of writing this:

```
Console.log "Server started and collections cleared."
```

Write it like this:

```
console.log "Server started and collections cleared."
```

Always write 'console' with a lowercase 'c' because JavaScript is a case sensitive language.

Comment: Your answer is correct. But please use some formatting to make it more clear.

Comment: You literally just copied the accepted answer 5 years later and added nothing new to it... How is this even getting votes?